# Need regex to locate c++ namespace declarations with unknown names

Tags: c++, regex, realbasic

I'm trying to understand open source c++ code and I need a way to create a list of all the declared namespaces. I'm writing my code in Xojo (realbasic) with has built-in regex handling.

My problem is I'm not familiar enough with regular expressions to construct the correct expression to locate "namespace " followed by an unknown name then " {" all on the same line of text.

I can code everything else myself, I just need the proper regular expression. All help appreciated.

Comment: You'd be better off using something like Doxygen, C++ is notoriously hard to parse (your simple definition could miss a lot of stuff and pick up stuff you don't want).

Comment: If you know it's all on the same line: `namespace (.+)? \{`

Comment: @Mat They make a Doxygen report available online. How would I get a namespace list from it?

Answer (score 1):

You may try `namespace\s+(\w+)\s*\{` for the most common cases without comments between words and won't match something like `using namespace std;`. Anyway namespaces can be nested, but here you'll get only flat list of all names.